# Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello i'm currently making my programm dynamically. This static code is working perfect;

```
      <Step name="question1">
        <div className="stepContent">
          <h4>Are you visiting Berlin alone?</h4>
          <Controls>
            {({ destinations: { question2, question3 } }) => (
              <div className="buttonContainer">
                <button onClick={question2}>Yes</button>
                <button onClick={question3}>No</button>
              </div>
            )}
          </Controls>
        </div>
```

But my dynamic code is causing this Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. Error

```
        <div className="buttonContainer">
          {block.nextTag.map((step, index) => (
            <Controls>
              {(destinations = step) => (
                <button onClick={step}>
                  {block.nextTagDesc[index]}
                </button>
              )}
            </Controls>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Thanks for help. If you need additional information just comment.

Comment: Is `onClick={step}` throwing the error?  If so, what is `step`?  The error itself is pretty clearly saying what's wrong.  It sounds like you expect something to be a function when at runtime it's a string.

Comment: the step is exactly how it is in the static example (question1. question2). I mean these are strings but its working in the static example and not in the dynamic and I don't get why.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing more assuming than debugging, which isn't going to get you far.  The `step` variable *isn't in* "the static example*, though there is a `Step` *component*, but how is that related?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem so we can observe it?

Comment: What do you think `destinations = step` is doing in the arrow function parameter list? Why are you declaring a parameter (`destinations`) that you never use? In the static example (well, both of them really), what's calling the function you're creating and passing to `Controls` as its child? What does that function get called with? It looks like it receives an object that has a `destinations` property that has `question2` and `question3` on it, but the dynamic version completely ignores that parameter and has seemingly-unrelated changes as well, so it's really hard to help you with this.

Comment: `onClick={step}` is only appropriate if `block.nextTag` is an array of functions.

Answer (score 0):

The error says answer at all you must have to pass function in your check the type of your "step" variable with `typeof(step)`

your function would be returning string try to pass a function inside your onclick